# Unable to import scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, visual-studio-code, scrapy, installation

I am trying to scrape a website. However, I get this error inside the VS Code editor:

```
Unable to import 'scrapy'pylint(import-error)
```

Unable to import 'scrapy'pylint(import-error) These are the important parts of codes I am using, I just didn't copy all the variables I am scraping:

```
 class xxxxxxxxSpider(scrapy.Spider):

name = 'xxxxxxx'
allowed_domains = 
['www.drsaina.com/ConsultationDoctor/%D9%85%D8%B4%D8%A7%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%87- 
 %D8%A2%D9%86%D9%84%D8%A7%DB%8C%D9%86']

start_urls =['https://www.drsaina.com/ConsultationDoctor/%D9%85%D8%B4%D8%A7%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%87 
- 
 %D8%A2%D9%86%D9%84%D8%A7%DB%8C%D9%86/']

def parse(self, response):
    specialties = response.xpath("//h3").getall()
    for specialty in specialties:
        name = specialty.xpath(".//text()").getall()
        link = specialty.xpath(".//@href").getall()
        yield response.follow(url=link, callback=self.parse_spacialty, meta = 
{'specialty_name':name})

def parse_spacialty(self, response):
    specialty_name = response.request.meta['specialty_name']
    specifications = response.xpath 
("/html/body/main/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/div/div")
    for specification in specifications:
        doctor_name = specification.xpath(".//div[1]/a[2]/span/text()").get()
        doctor_specialty = specification.xpath 
(".//div[1]/a[2]/label/text()").get()
yield{
            'specialty_name':specialty_name,
            'doctor_name':doctor_name,
            'doctor_specialty':doctor_specialty,
}
```

Also in prompt, when I run my crawler, this is the whole error I got (@gangabass):

```
2020-05-17 08:48:05 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.1.0 started (bot: yyyyy)
2020-05-17 08:48:05 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.0.0, libxml2 2.9
.5, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.5.2, w3lib 1.21.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.7.7 (d
efault, May  6 2020, 11:45:54) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (Op
enSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020), cryptography 2.9.2, Platform Windows-8.1-6.3.9600-SP
0
2020-05-17 08:48:05 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: 
twisted.internet.se
lectreactor.SelectReactor
2020-05-17 08:48:05 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'yyyyy',
'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'yyyyy.spiders',
'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
'SPIDER_MODULES': ['yyyyy.spiders']}
2020-05-17 08:48:06 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 
6aefdde1ca
e354cd
2020-05-17 08:48:06 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
 ['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
 2020-05-17 08:48:07 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader 
middleware:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
 2020-05-17 08:48:07 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middleware:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2020-05-17 08:48:07 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2020-05-17 08:48:07 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-05-17 08:48:07 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 
0 page
es/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-05-17 08:48:07 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console 
listening on
127.0.0.1:6023
2020-05-17 08:48:08 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET 
https://www.d
rsaina.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2020-05-17 08:48:09 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET 
https://www.d
rsaina.com/ConsultationDoctor/%D9%85%D8%B4%D8%A7%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%87- 
%D8%A2%D9%86%
D9%84%D8%A7%DB%8C%D9%86/> (referer: None)
2020-05-17 08:48:09 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing 
<GET https:// 
www.drsaina.com/ConsultationDoctor/%D9%85%D8%B4%D8%A7%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%87-%D
8%A2%D9%86%D9%84%D8%A7%DB%8C%D9%86/> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\pc\anaconda3\envs\vitual_workspace\lib\site- 
 packages\scrapy\uti
ls\defer.py", line 117, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "c:\users\pc\anaconda3\envs\vitual_workspace\lib\site- 
packages\scrapy\uti
ls\python.py", line 345, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "c:\users\pc\anaconda3\envs\vitual_workspace\lib\site- 
packages\scrapy\uti
ls\python.py", line 345, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "c:\users\pc\anaconda3\envs\vitual_workspace\lib\site- 
packages\scrapy\cor
e\spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\users\pc\anaconda3\envs\vitual_workspace\lib\site- 
packages\scrapy\spi
dermiddlewares\offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "c:\users\pc\anaconda3\envs\vitual_workspace\lib\site- 
packages\scrapy\cor
e\spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\users\pc\anaconda3\envs\vitual_workspace\lib\site- 
packages\scrapy\spi
dermiddlewares\referer.py", line 338, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "c:\users\pc\anaconda3\envs\vitual_workspace\lib\site- 
packages\scrapy\cor
e\spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
    File "c:\users\pc\anaconda3\envs\vitual_workspace\lib\site- 
 packages\scrapy\spi
dermiddlewares\urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
     return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
   File "c:\users\pc\anaconda3\envs\vitual_workspace\lib\site- 
packages\scrapy\cor
e\spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
     for r in iterable:
   File "c:\users\pc\anaconda3\envs\vitual_workspace\lib\site- 
 packages\scrapy\spi
 dermiddlewares\depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
     return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "c:\users\pc\anaconda3\envs\vitual_workspace\lib\site- 
 packages\scrapy\cor
  e\spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
     for r in iterable:
    File "C:\Users\pc\projects\yyyyy\yyyyy\spiders\xxxxxxx.py", line 19, 
in parse
    name = specialty.xpath(".//text()").getall()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'xpath'
2020-05-17 08:48:09 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-05-17 08:48:09 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 533,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 44999,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 1.774663,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 17, 4, 18, 9, 761477),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'spider_exceptions/AttributeError': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 17, 4, 18, 7, 986814)}
2020-05-17 08:48:09 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Can someone help me out with this issue?

By the way, I am using the latest version I scrapy (2.1.0) and python 3

Comment: Please share at least the important parts of your code, otherwise helping you with debugging is quite impossible.

Comment: The code editor error suggests that Pylint does not see Scrapy installed. Is Pylint running in the same Python environment where Scrapy is installed? (same version of Python, same virtual environment if you are using virtual environments)

Comment: Hello @Gallaecio, yes I checked it, it is installed, yet it says unable to import scrapy

Comment: I cannot help with your specific IDE, but I suggest you search for help about that issue, how to get your IDE to use the same Python environment where you installed Scrapy.